# MySQL was killed by watchdog/snapd ubuntu ec2, watchdog is not installed but listing in ps

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, kill, out-of-memory

On one of my servers mysql was killed because of too much memory usage. Before it crashed the memory usage was around 95%. My confusion is what killed the process because I have seen in past whenever the process is killed because of OutOfMemory it clearly logs it in syslog.

In the log I see that the process restarted but I can't figure out which process stopped/killed it.

Logs from journalcntrl.

```
Apr 30 19:08:45 ip-10-0-1-4 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Watchdog timeout (limit 5min)!
Apr 30 19:08:57 ip-10-0-1-4 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Killing process 24259 (snapd) with signal SIGABRT.
Apr 30 19:09:17 ip-10-0-1-4 systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Community Server...
Apr 30 19:09:18 ip-10-0-1-4 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
Apr 30 19:09:18 ip-10-0-1-4 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'watchdog'.
Apr 30 19:09:18 ip-10-0-1-4 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
Apr 30 19:09:18 ip-10-0-1-4 systemd[1]: Starting Failure handling of the snapd snap...
Apr 30 19:09:18 ip-10-0-1-4 systemd[1]: Started Failure handling of the snapd snap.
Apr 30 19:09:18 ip-10-0-1-4 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 30 19:09:18 ip-10-0-1-4 systemd[1]: snapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 13.
Apr 30 19:09:18 ip-10-0-1-4 systemd[1]: Stopped Snappy daemon.
Apr 30 19:09:18 ip-10-0-1-4 systemd[1]: Starting Snappy daemon...
Apr 30 19:09:18 ip-10-0-1-4 snapd[11960]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
Apr 30 19:09:18 ip-10-0-1-4 CRON[11772]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 30 19:09:19 ip-10-0-1-4 snapd[11960]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
Apr 30 19:09:19 ip-10-0-1-4 snapd[11960]: daemon.go:343: started snapd/2.44.3 (series 16; classic) ubuntu/18.04 (amd64) linux/4.15.0-1041-aws.
Apr 30 19:09:19 ip-10-0-1-4 snapd[11960]: daemon.go:436: adjusting startup timeout by 40s (pessimistic estimate of 30s plus 5s per snap)
Apr 30 19:09:19 ip-10-0-1-4 systemd[1]: Started Snappy daemon.
Apr 30 19:09:20 ip-10-0-1-4 snapd[11960]: storehelpers.go:438: cannot refresh: snap has no updates available: "amazon-ssm-agent", "core"
Apr 30 19:09:20 ip-10-0-1-4 snapd[11960]: autorefresh.go:397: auto-refresh: all snaps are up-to-date
Apr 30 19:09:21 ip-10-0-1-4 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Apr 30 19:09:21 ip-10-0-1-4 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Apr 30 19:09:22 ip-10-0-1-4 systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.cd
```

I see that the mysql process was started back on by monit.

```
[UTC Apr 30 19:07:14] error    : 'mysql' failed protocol test [MYSQL] at [localhost]:3306 [TCP/IP] -- Error receiving server response -- Resource temporarily unavailable
-- stop/start log
```

Also when I see `ps -ef | grep watchdog` I see it running but I can't find the command.

```
root@ip-10-0-1-4:/var/log# ps -ef | grep watch
root        11     2  0  2019 ?        00:00:33 [watchdog/0]
root        14     2  0  2019 ?        00:00:31 [watchdog/1]
root        20     2  0  2019 ?        00:00:27 [watchdog/2]
root        26     2  0  2019 ?        00:00:28 [watchdog/3]
root        32     2  0  2019 ?        00:00:28 [watchdog/4]
root        38     2  0  2019 ?        00:00:26 [watchdog/5]
root        44     2  0  2019 ?        00:00:26 [watchdog/6]
root        50     2  0  2019 ?        00:00:33 [watchdog/7]
root        75     2  0  2019 ?        00:00:00 [watchdogd]
```

what is this process? I haven't seen it before.

Let me know if any other information required.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running a Snap version of Mysql? It looks like snapd hit some limit / timeout and killed the process itself before it got to the kernel oom. I don't think the watchdogs you see in ps are related, they are part of watchdogd. That is a system that will restart your server if it's unresponsive. Check if you have a /dev/watchdog file that is being updated every so often.

Comment: I checked mysql was installed from apt and not snap. `/dev/watchdog` file is not present. Snap should not be killing any processes. I want mysql be the highest priority process, everything else should be killed before mysql server.